# is it possible to switch controller of a view to something else

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to use custom controller for a view based on a parameter. The controller is not the in the route chain so I don't think I can use "needs". This is what I tried and it didn't work well for me!

```
App.MyBasicsView = Ember.View.extend({
    //TRY 1: failed 
    initialize: function () {
        var someParam = get some param from default controller;//failed controller is not set at this instance
        //based on someParam initialize a controller and set this to the view
    }.on('init')

    //TRY 2 : no errors but the template doesn't render
    setController: function(){
        var container = this.get("controller.container"),
        model = this.get("controller.model"),
        controller = MY-CUSTOM-CONTROLLER.create({'container': container, 'model': model});
        this.set('controller', controller);
    }.observes('controller.someParam')

...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation it is better to use `Ember.Component` not `Ember.View` and pass your model from template

for example:

> someParam is property in controller

```
{{my-basics myBasicProperty=someParam}}
```

Comment: Yeah i thought about that one too, its definitely one of the solution but i would have to use separate component based on the "param". My basics view corresponds to a route, so i will have to embed this dynamic component within the view, i tried setting template of the view by doing Ember.Handlebars.compile('my param specific view'), i didnt have much luck and since component extends view i think i will run into same problem. I will give this another try though. Thanks.

Comment: Also just wanted to get an opinion, what if i used render helper instead of components?

Answer (score 0):

Ok we ended up using rederTemplate hook in the route like this:

```
renderTemplate: function (controller, model) {
    var questionType = some-type,
        controllerName = (questionType.classify())+"BasicsController",
        template = 'views.questions.basics.' + questionType + "-question",
        typeBasedController = controller;

    //if cannot resolve the template then use the default template
    template = (this.container.resolve('template:' + template)) ? template : 'views.questions.basics.default-question';
    var factory = this.container.lookupFactory('controller:' + controllerName);
    if (factory) {
        typeBasedController = factory.create({'model': model });
    }

    this.render(template, {
        'controller': typeBasedController
    });
}
```

It basically lets us use the controller and view we desire. And now in latest ember version, its even more simpler using tbe with helper like this:

```
{{#with model controller="myDesiredController}}
.......
{{/with}}
```